# Chrome 93+ ignoring SQLite Triggers

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, chromium

Since I updated Chromium from version v91 to v93 it is no longer respecting the following trigger I cretated inside the `history` (which is a sqlite3 file) in the user profile:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS no_urls BEFORE INSERT ON urls FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ABORT, ''); END;
```

This trigger used to work fine preventing Chrome from saving any history on my profile.

Now, since v93 it somehow bypasses that trigger and keep storing the urls (history).

Is there a trick to make Chrome respect that trigger and do not save history?

[image]

Comment: Maybe they turned off triggers in Chrome's connections to the database.

Comment: Chromium now [disables all triggers](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+blame/refs/heads/main/sql/database.cc#1580).

Comment: @AnonCoward post as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure the answer is:  You can't do this.

From a recent check in to the [source code to Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+blame/refs/heads/main/sql/database.cc#1580):

```c
// The use of triggers is discouraged for Chrome code. Thanks to this
// configuration change, triggers are not executed. CREATE TRIGGER and DROP
// TRIGGER still succeed.
err = sqlite3_db_config(db_, SQLITE_DBCONFIG_ENABLE_TRIGGER, 0, nullptr);
```

They appear to be explicitly disabling the SQLite trigger functionality, with no option or configuration around it.

Short of convincing them to change this behavior, or creating a custom build, I don't see any way around this.